My mini cube wont register to API server and TCP keeps shutting down I've stopped and started the service 100 times with different combinations of cmd
PS C:\\Windows\\system32\\submarine\> minikube addons enable yakd
! yakd is a 3rd party addon and is not maintained or verified by minikube maintainers, enable at your own risk.

* yakd is maintained by 3rd party (marcnuri.com) for any concerns contact manusa on GitHub.
  - Using image docker.io/marcnuri/yakd:0.0.4

X Exiting due to MK_ADDON_ENABLE: enable failed: run callbacks: running callbacks: \[sudo KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/minikube/k
beconfig /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.30.0/kubectl apply --force -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-ns.yaml -f /etc/kubern
tes/addons/yakd-sa.yaml -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-crb.yaml -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-svc.yaml -f /etc/kuberne
es/addons/yakd-dp.yaml: Process exited with status 1
stdout:

stderr:
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-ns.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:/
localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore t
ese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-sa.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:/
localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore t
ese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-crb.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:
/localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore
hese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-svc.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:
/localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore
hese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-dp.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:/
localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore t
ese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
\]
\*
?─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────?
│                                                                                             │
│    \* If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                                 │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                               │
│                                                                                             │
│    \* Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│    \* Please also attach the following file to the GitHub issue:                             │
│    \* - C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\minikube_addons_86fabb042c5e6dfc0f5c4c2876cb292cb27ac931_0.log       │
│                                                                                             │
?─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────?

PS C:\Windows\system32\submarine> minikube addons enable yakd
! yakd is a 3rd party addon and is not maintained or verified by minikube maintainers, enable at your own risk.
* yakd is maintained by 3rd party (marcnuri.com) for any concerns contact manusa on GitHub.
  - Using image docker.io/marcnuri/yakd:0.0.4

X Exiting due to MK_ADDON_ENABLE: enable failed: run callbacks: running callbacks: [sudo KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/minikube/k
beconfig /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.30.0/kubectl apply --force -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-ns.yaml -f /etc/kubern
tes/addons/yakd-sa.yaml -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-crb.yaml -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-svc.yaml -f /etc/kuberne
es/addons/yakd-dp.yaml: Process exited with status 1
stdout:

stderr:
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-ns.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:/
localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore t
ese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-sa.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:/
localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore t
ese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-crb.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:
/localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore
hese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-svc.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:
/localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore
hese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/yakd-dp.yaml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https:/
localhost:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused; if you choose to ignore t
ese errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
]
*
?─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────?
│                                                                                             │
│    * If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                                 │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                               │
│                                                                                             │
│    * Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│    * Please also attach the following file to the GitHub issue:                             │
│    * - C:\Windows\TEMP\minikube_addons_86fabb042c5e6dfc0f5c4c2876cb292cb27ac931_0.log       │
│                                                                                             │
?─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────?

